# Transforming data from one column to more

Tags: excel, powerquery, excel-365

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUy0d.png)

I need to have this data in four different rows in Power Query.

Can someone help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: The input is all on one row?  Show an example of your output

Comment: I solved the issue using Line Feed. Thanks.